# What does AndroidStudio do in indexing?

Tags: android-studio

As the question mentions, what happens when AndroidStudio does indexing? What is the use of indexing?

Could somebody please help me understand.

Answer (score -1):

from https://www.jetbrains.com/ 
while Android studio is using InteliJ idea :

> Indexing in IntelliJ IDEA is responsible for the core features of the
> IDE: code completion, inspections, finding usages, navigation, syntax
> highlighting, and refactorings.
>
> It starts when you open your project, switch between branches, after
> you load or unload plugins, and after large external file updates. For
> example, this can happen if multiple files in your project are created
> or generated after you build your project.

you can read more about IntelliJ indexing here https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/indexing.html